# Extract values from href attribute string using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to extract values from href attribute string using JQuery

```
$(this).attr("href")
```

will give me

```
?sortdir=ASC&sort=Vendor_Name
```

What i need is these values parsed into an array

```
myArray['sort']

myArray['sortdir']
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

BTW , I saw somewhere else on SO the following similar idea to be used with a query string.
I could not tweak it for my needs just yet.

```
var urlParams = {};
    (function () {
        var match,
    pl = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
    query = window.location.search.substring(1);

        while (match = search.exec(query))
            urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695147/how-to-change-css-attribute-value-based-on-querystring-using-jquery#answer-8695175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function getURLParameter(name, string) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(string)||[,null])[1]
    );
}

var string = $(this).attr("href");

alert(getURLParameter("sort",string));
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/jbHa6/   You can change the var string value and play around.

**EDIT**

Removed the second example, since that code is not that good and does not serve the purpose.

Comment: thanks so much the first approach worked like a dandy.  If that is a compliment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var href = $(this).attr("href")
href = href.replace('?', "").split('&');

var myArr = {};
$.each(href, function(i, v){
   var s = v.split('=');
   myArr[s[0]] = s[1];    
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sv75f/)

Comment: @Pinch have you checked the fiddle? it's an object and it's not empty.

Comment: Your approach works as well, i am still unable to give you a +1, until my rep goes up.. anyone else please give him a +1!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is there a better solution but to be quick I should have do something like that

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
url = url.replace("?sortdir=", "");
url = url.replace("sort=", "");
myArray['sort'] = url.split("&")[1]; // Or use a temporary tab for your split
myArray['sortdir'] = url.split("&")[0];
```

That solution depends if your url is still like ?sortdir=ASC&sort=Vendor_Name

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery BBQ's deparam function from here:

http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/